# How to join tables and apply where clause for active record RAILS

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

This seems like a very simple thing to do but despite looking through the rails docs it's not working like I expect. I'm likely making an incorrect assumption somewhere. Maybe I'm trying to get activerecord to be used for something it is not intended for?

I'm trying to join my Books table and Checkout_logs table and only return records matching user_id and with returned_date of null (nil)

I'm trying to do something like this example in sql (except list all the book info not just title and get user_id from parameters)

```
select b.title,c.due_date from 
(select * from books) b
JOIN
(select * from checkout_logs) c
ON b.id = c.book_id
where c.user_id = 1 and returned_date is null
```

This is my attempt

books_controller.rb

```
def my_books    
    @books = Book.joins(:checkout_logs).where(user_id: params[:user_id], returned_date: nil)
  end
```

and view

my_books.html.erb

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Genre</th>
      <th>Subgenre</th>
      <th>Pages</th>
      <th>Publisher</th>      
      <th>due_date</th>
      <th colspan="1"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @books.each do |book| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to book.title, book %></td>
        <td><%= book.author %></td>
        <td><%= book.genre %></td>
        <td><%= book.subgenre %></td>
        <td><%= book.pages %></td>
        <td><%= book.publisher %></td>
        <td><%= book.due_date %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Return', books_return_path %></td>        
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

book.rb

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :checkout_logs, dependent: :destroy
end
```

checkout_log.rb

```
class CheckoutLog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
end
```

It gives an error upon loading the view that books.user_id doesn't exist or books.due_date doesn't exist. I understand books doesn't have those things but I thought that by joining it with checkout_log I would be able to access them that way?

I'd prefer to learn how to do this in activerecord because I assume it is the best practice. I'm open to using another method. I have another page that does something similar using AREL, but I'd prefer to clean that up too if I can learn how to use activerecord better.

Comment: `where(checkout_logs: {user_id: params[:user_id], returned_date: nil})`

Answer (score 1):

You can debug your queries by passing `.to_sql` to them

```
 @books = 
   Book
   .joins(:checkout_logs)
   .where(user_id: params[:user_id], returned_date: nil)
```

in this case, I think the problem is that the `where` conditions are made against `books` table instead of `checkout_logs` table. You can fix this by doing

```
.where(checkout_logs: { user_id: params[:user_id], returned_date: nil })
```

Comment: The main issue is that regardless of the where clause I can't access things in the checkout_logs table e.g. book.due_date. Even if I remove the where clause entirely I only have access to things in the book table. So the issue is around the join or something inherent to how activerecord works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the where clause. In the where clause, you need to traverse the relationship to access the attributes on the correct table. There is no user_id on the book table. Im assuming the returned date is on the CheckoutLog table as well. If you cahnge your query to this, it should be ok.

`Book.joins(:checkout_logs).where(checkout_logs: {user_id: params[:user_id], returned_date: nil})`

To get the checkout log information here, you need to iterate through the relationship.

```rb
@book.checkout_logs.each do |log|
  puts log.due_date
  ...
end
```

A better way of doing the above would be to use includes and/or references to eager load the related checkout logs to reduce n+1 issues

If you just want the CheckoutLog records, then you need to start on that model.

`CheckoutLog.where(book_id: <BOOK ID>, user_id: params[:user_id], returned_date: nil)`

And then you could iterate through those in your view to get whatever checkout log information you needed.

Comment: That does make the where clause work. The problem is still I can't access Book.due_date (a column from checkout_logs) in my view after I join the tables. If I remove all checkout_log columns from my view it will display the correct records based on my where clause, but I need to include that column in the view. So it's something to do with the relationship? model?

Comment: The books due date is in the checkout logs table? Then you'd need to iterate through the book's checkout logs, `@book.checkout_logs.each { |log| log.due_date }`. If you're trying to get JUST the checkout logs and access those for a particuular book then you need to start on the CheckouLog model, `CheckoutLog.where(book_id: <ID>, user_id: params[:user_id], returned_date: nil)` That will give you all the checkout logs that you can then iterate through for that

Comment: Yes, due date is in the checkout_logs table (each entry represents borrowing a book from the library). This particular page needs all the book information (from books table) and the due date from checkout_logs table. Is there no way to join two tables and display information from the combined table in rails? I figured this would be straight forward.

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer with that information. To get the book info, you start with the original answer I gave. Then in your view, you need to iterate through the checkout_logs relationship. If it's an api then you need to add that association to the serializer

Comment: So I got it working by doing checkout_log joins books because a checkout_log has exactly 1 book I'm able to access it in the view by doing e.g. checkout_log.book.title. Whereas I couldn't set it up the way I was trying and wouldn't have been able to get those fields from the other models. Thanks for helping me get there!

Answer (score 0):

So I needed to do the following in

book_controllers.rb

```
@checkout_logs = CheckoutLog.joins(:book).where(checkout_logs: {user_id: current_user.id, returned_date: nil})
```

and then the view can access the book by doing:

my_books.html.erb

```
<% @checkout_logs.each do |checkout_log| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= checkout_log.book.title %></td>
        <td><%= checkout_log.book.author %></td>
        <td><%= checkout_log.book.genre %></td>
        <td><%= checkout_log.book.subgenre %></td>
        <td><%= checkout_log.book.pages %></td>
        <td><%= checkout_log.book.publisher %></td>
        <td><%= checkout_log.due_date %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Return', books_return_path(:checkout_log_id => checkout_log.id) %></td>        
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Because checkout_log has 1 book I can access the book this way. I can't access the information the other way around or create some hybrid that has it all on the same level. (at least I wasn't able to)

Comment: You should change the `joins` to an `includes` like I suggest in the answer I provided where I covered this scenario. The includes will ensure no n+1 query